# Is it possible to have an array of structs which conform to the same protocol also support Codable?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, codable, swift-protocols

I have setup the following protocol, and have 2 structs which then conform to this protocol:

```
protocol ExampleProtocol: Decodable {
    var name: String { get set }
    var length: Int { get set }
}

struct ExampleModel1: ExampleProtocol {
    var name: String
    var length: Int
    var otherData: Array<String>
}

struct ExampleModel2: ExampleProtocol {
    var name: String
    var length: Int
    var dateString: String
}
```

I want to deserialise some JSON data I receive from the server, and I know it will be returning a mix of both ExampleModel1 and ExampleModel2 in an array:

```
struct ExampleNetworkResponse: Decodable {
    var someString: String
    var modelArray: Array<ExampleProtocol>
}
```

Is there anyway to use the Codable approach and support both models easily? Or will I need to manually deserialise the data for each model?

EDIT 1:

Conforming to Decodable on the structs, still gives the same results:

```
struct ExampleModel1: ExampleProtocol, Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, length, otherData
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.length = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .length)
        self.otherData = try container.decode(Array<String>.self, forKey: .otherData)
    }

    var name: String
    var length: Int
    var otherData: Array<String>
}

struct ExampleModel2: ExampleProtocol, Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, length, dateString
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.length = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .length)
        self.dateString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dateString)
    }

    var name: String
    var length: Int
    var dateString: String
}

struct ExampleNetworkResponse: Decodable {
    var someString: String
    var modelArray: Array<ExampleProtocol>
}
```

Comment: conforming to a protocol is not inheritance, so exampleprotocol is decodable not exampleModel1 and exampleModel2 are not decodable, so you must conform to Decodable in each struct

Comment: @kjoe Can you give an example, I've tried conforming them to Decodable but it still has the same issue. I'm guessing this is due to the protocol being the array type. See Edit 1, I think this is what you mean?

Comment: you cannot expect to decode a exampleModel1 from Example protocol since the decode func is not expecting otherData and DateString. do you know when is exampleModel1 and two are coming from json in the order or could both in random order

Comment: @kjoe No the order can be completely random, and there are currently 6 different models. Hence why I wanted to try and generically handle them, rather than on a per object basis.

Comment: so if the order is unknot I guess that you must catch for error and try other model and so until you decode the right one. just like the answer of samps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a limited amount of `ExampleProtocol`s and you need to have a different type of ExampleProtocols in the same array, then you can create a holder for `ExampleProtocol` and use it for decoding/encoding.

ExampleHolder could hold all possible Decodable ExampleProtocol types in one array. So decoder init don't need to have so many if-else scopes and easier to add more in the future.

Would recommend keeping ExampleHolder as a private struct. So it's not possible to access it outside of file or maybe even not outside of ExampleNetworkResponse.

```swift
enum ExampleNetworkResponseError: Error {
    case unsupportedExampleModelOnDecoding
}

private struct ExampleHolder: Decodable {
    let exampleModel: ExampleProtocol

    private let possibleModelTypes: [ExampleProtocol.Type] = [
        ExampleModel1.self,
        ExampleModel2.self
    ]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        for type in possibleModelTypes {
            if let model = try? type.init(from: decoder) {
                exampleModel = model
                return
            }
        }

        throw ExampleNetworkResponseError.unsupportedExampleModelOnDecoding
    }
}

struct ExampleNetworkResponse: Decodable {
    var someString: String
    var modelArray: Array<ExampleProtocol>

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case someString, modelArray
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        someString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .someString)
        let exampleHolderArray = try container.decode([ExampleHolder].self, forKey: .modelArray)
        modelArray = exampleHolderArray.map({ $0.exampleModel })
    }
}
```

–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

If in one response can have only one type of `ExampleProtocol` in the array then:

```swift
struct ExampleNetworkResponse2<ModelArrayElement: ExampleProtocol>: Decodable {
    var someString: String
    var modelArray: Array<ModelArrayElement>
}
```

usage:

```swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let response = try decoder.decode(
    ExampleNetworkResponse2<ExampleModel1>.self,
    from: dataToDecode
)
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks so much for this, will give it a try now! Indepth answer, really appreciate it :)