# Swift: Decode message sent from GameKit

Tags: swift, codable, jsondecoder

I'm trying to receive messages in GameKit. The part of receiving the messages works well, but I can not figure out how to decode the data properly.

```
enum MessageType: Int, Codable {
    case BestHost, GameBegin, YourTurn, PlayCard, GameOver
}

struct Message: Codable {
    let messageType: MessageType
    }

struct MessageBestHost: Codable {
    let message: Message
    let bestHostId: String
    let bestHostName: String
}
```

---

I use the above infrastructure for sending and receiving my messages. For sending I encode the message as follows and then send it to all players:

```
func encode<T: Encodable>(_ item: T) throws -> Data {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    return try encoder.encode(item)
}

func sendBestHost(player: GKPlayer) {

    let message = MessageBestHost(message: Message(messageType: MessageType.BestHost), bestHostId: player.gamePlayerID, bestHostName: player.alias)
    do {
        try sendDataToAllPlayers(data: encode(message))
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

---

When receiving I use this method to decode the data:

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(from data:Data) throws -> T {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let item = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
  return item
}

let message: Message
do {
    message = try decode (from: data)
    print(message)
} catch {
    print (error)
}

if message.messageType == MessageType.BestHost {
    do {
    let messageBestHost: MessageBestHost = try decode(from: data)
    print("\(messageBestHost.bestHostName) hosts the game")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

The problem now is. I first need to decode the message as type: Message in order to filter for the correct Subtype and do the magic for the referencing messageType. When trying to cast the data into a variable of type message, the decoding (obviously) fails because the sent data does not contain a messageType in the top hierarchical level.

```
Error: No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"messageType\", intValue: nil)
```

Without being able to filter for the messageType first I won't be able to distinguish between different messages and execute different methods.

I guess the solution might lay within my data infrastructure but I cant think of any way to make this work. Does anybody have a clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: Will there be different types of Message or MessageBestHost according to type itself?
If so, then maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270672/is-it-possible-to-have-an-array-of-structs-which-conform-to-the-same-protocol-al/59271924#59271924
If not, then I didn't understand why you can't first decode it to MessageBestHost and then filter them afterward.

Comment: There are all types of messages mentioned `mesasageType`. I just used MessageBestHost as an example. That is why I cannot decode it to MessageBestHost all the time, because the messageType will change and will not always contain the same data. I just had a look on the provided link. There you work with protocols. I can’t connect your example to mine because I don’t use protocols. You think using protocols would be the right approach here? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you need to use the  MessageBestHost. If in the array, then they should conform to the same protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try something like this:

```
import Foundation

enum MessageType: Int, Codable {
    case BestHost, GameBegin, YourTurn, PlayCard, GameOver
}

struct Message: Codable {
    let messageType: MessageType
    let data: Data
}

struct MessageBestHost: Codable {
    let bestHostId: String
    let bestHostName: String
}

do {
    // Serialize:

    let messageBestHost = MessageBestHost(bestHostId: "id", bestHostName: "name")
    let messageBestHostData = try JSONEncoder().encode(messageBestHost)
    let message = Message(messageType: .BestHost, data: messageBestHostData)
    let messageData = try JSONEncoder().encode(message)
    try sendDataToAllPlayers(data: encode(message))

    // Deserialize:
    let messageReceived = try JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: messageData)
    if messageReceived.messageType == .BestHost {
        let messageBestHostReceived = try JSONDecoder().decode(MessageBestHost.self, from: messageReceived.data)
        print(messageBestHostReceived.bestHostId)
        print(messageBestHostReceived.bestHostName)
    }

} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Also swift enum cases should start with lowercase letter